# MYSQL : Deleting a row after UPDATE in scheduled event

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have a event that selects this result from a larger table
The query is:

```
UPDATE character_data tu, character_data ts 
SET tu.killsZ = ts.killsZ 
WHERE tu.playerUID = ts.playerUID 
    and tu.numberid < ts.numberid;

numberid  |  playerUID  |  alive  |  killsZ
   1           555555        0         55
   2           555555        1         55
```

The event is simply

```
1. UPDATE character_data tu, character_data ts 
   SET tu.killsZ = ts.killsZ 
   WHERE tu.playerUID = ts.playerUID 
       and tu.numberid < ts.numberid;
2. DELETE FROM character_data 
   WHERE alive = 0 
   GROUP BY playerUID 
   HAVING COUNT(playerUID) > 1;
```

This line seems to be not be working correctly:

```
DELETE FROM character_data 
WHERE alive = 0 
GROUP BY playerUID 
HAVING COUNT(playerUID) > 1;
```

The wierd thing is that it will delete all the rows where `alive = 1` but not `0`.

If i do this:

```
DELETE FROM character_data 
WHERE alive = 1 
GROUP BY playerUID 
HAVING COUNT(playerUID) > 1;
```

It will delete all rows where alive = 0 but every now and then it will delete the right row. Why is this doing the reverse and how can i get a reliable result?

Comment: I'm having a hard time grokking your use of group by and having in a delete statement. Does everything in the group get deleted if the having clause comes back true?

Comment: I want it to only delete the row where the alive = 0 if there are more than 1 row with identical playerUID's. To answer your question, only 1 line of the 2 lines is deleted, however the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
    delete from character_data  where playeruid in
(select t1.playeruid from character_data1 t1 where playeruid=t1.playeruid 
and killsz=t1.killsz and alive=0 
group by playeruid having count(*)>1) limit 1
```

**Note:**

It works only when there are 2 duplicate records.If you have three duplicate playerid's and want to delete 2 of them then you should change the limit to 2 manually.The table character_data1 is a temporary table created by me and you **cant use** the **same table inside sub-queries when using the delete function** so you should create a duplicate table to do your task.

Comment: Yea, this is exactly what i need, however, its giving a syntax error at 'character_data t'

Comment: I have edited check it out.The problem is you should not use aliases for the table on which delete is applied.

Comment: Now getting table character_data1 doesnt exist

Comment: You should create a new table called character_data1 with same contents as character_data in other words you should create a duplicate table.Please read my note.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, if I read this correctly, is delete the rows where alive = 0 but only for those with playerUID values appearing more than once. So what you are looking for is a list of playerUID values that have at least one duplicate:

```
select playerUID
from character_data
group by playerUID
having count(*) > 1
```

Then use that list to delete where alive = 0:

```
delete from character_data
where alive = 0
and playerUID in( query-shown-above );
```

Comment: It won't work you can't use the table where delete statement is used in the subquery.

Comment: No problem. All OP has to do is switch to Oracle where it does work...;)
OK, I can't come up with a single-statement solution for MySql off the top of my head, so it looks like the temp table is king here.

Comment: Yeah you are right but the user has tagged mysql in the question so I guess it is not relevant to post oracle solution.Anyways thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest the following query for deleting:

```
DELETE FROM character_data 
WHERE alive = 0 
and playerUID is not null
```

I don't see what the group by and having really get you

Comment: That would be correct, but the problem is there are multiple playerUID's in this table where alive = 0 and i don't want them all deleted, just the ones that having matching playerUID's

Comment: This query would delete all the rows where alive is zero and player is is not empty.